# Seeking Literature on Triple Difference (DDD) for Heterogeneous Effects in DD Evaluation

Tags: references, econometrics, difference-in-difference

I'm currently exploring the use of difference-in-differences (DD) for my evaluation and have estimated my primary DD effects. I'm interested in understanding if there are differentiated effects between genders. My initial assumption is that I might need to employ a triple difference (DDD) approach to capture this.

Could anyone recommend literature or papers that explicitly use a DDD approach to estimate heterogeneous effects in a DD evaluation? Specifically, I'm keen on examples that delve into gender differences.

Answer (score 0):

you have both
Duflo, Esther (2001) ‘Schooling and labor market consequences of school construction in Indonesia: Evidence from an unusual policy experiment, The American Economic Review , Sep., 2001, Vol. 91, No. 4 (Sep., 2001), pp. 795-
813
and
on gender issues:
Women's political participation and intrahousehold empowerment: Evidence from the Egyptian Arab Spring
https://ideas.repec.org/p/hal/cdiwps/halshs-01804380.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/360456)